# Unable to change Organizer While creating google calendar event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, icalendar, google-api-nodejs-client

I wanna use google calendar API for meeting invites for my application. I have authorized using service account keys for API. But I'm unable to change the organizer for an event. Therefore, even I used move() to change but didn't changed . Can anyone suggest me a solution for the calendar invites to change the organizer.

```
var { google } = require("googleapis");
var serviceAccount = require("../config/servicekeys.json");
const scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events', 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    serviceAccount.client_email,
    null,
    serviceAccount.private_key,
    scopes,
    "hello@example.com", //GSuite admin mail id
    'serviceAccount_id' //Service account client id
    
);
//authenticate request
jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully connected!", tokens);
    }
});


const api = google.calendar({ version: "v3", auth: jwtClient });

var event = {
    'summary': 'Calendar Service',
    'description': 'Meeting Invite',
    'start': {
        'dateTime': '2021-09-30T18:00:00', 
    },
    'end': {
        'dateTime': '2021-09-30T19:00:00', 
    },
    'attendees': [
        {
            organizer: true,
            rsvp: true,
            responseStatus: 'needsAction',
            displayName: 'Krishna durga',
            email: 'durga.dasari@gmail.com',
        },
        {
            rsvp: true,
            responseStatus: 'needsAction',
            displayName: "sai krishna",
            email: "krishnadurga@gmail.com",
        }
    ],
    organizer: {
        rsvp: true,
        responseStatus: 'needsAction',
        displayName: 'Krishna durga',
        email: 'durga.dasari@gmail.com',
    },
    guestsCanSeeOtherGuests: true,
    'guestsCanInviteOthers': true,
    'visibility': 'public',
    'reminders': {
        'useDefault': false,
        'overrides': [
            { 'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60 },
            { 'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10 },
        ]
    },
}


var event = api.events.insert({
    calendarId: 'primary',
    resource: event,
    sendNotifications: true,
    sendUpdates: 'all',
}, function (err, event) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error contacting the Calendar service: ' + err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Event created: ', event);
    if (err) return console.error(err);
}); 

enter code here var event = api.events.move({
    calendarId: 'primary',
    eventId: 'jg05ujsobutue8kbt01ldg1u7o',
    destination: 'xyz@gmail.com',
    // resource: event,
    sendNotifications: true,
    sendUpdates: 'all',
}, function (err, event) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error contacting the Calendar service while moving: ' + err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Event created for organizer: %s', event);
    if (err) return console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Can you provide your API requests?

Comment: hi @RafaGuillermo I have api request above please refer the code suggest me a solution to change organizer. Thank you

Comment: What errors do you get when attempting to make the call?